# Как остановить запущенный javaw процесс (через cmd/batch)

Tags: java, bat

Я запускаю java приложение следующим образом:
`start "some app" javaw %JAVA_OPTS%`

Далее мне нужен скрипт, который остановит этот процесс.
Я пробую так:
`TASKKILL /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq some app"`
Но выводится что по этому условию задачи не найдены.

Указанная команда остановки отрабатывает в случае когда я использую `start java`, вместо `start javaw`. Но start java запуcкает командное окно, что мне не нужно. Как задать имя в случае с javaw,
для последующей остановки?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
taskkill /f /im javaw.exe
```

Comment: Не уверен что это сработает в случае, когда запущено несколько сервисов. Остановятся лишние сервисы.